# Hibernate PooledOptimizer primary key violation in Cluster environment

Tags: hibernate, caching, jakarta-ee, cluster-computing

I was facing Primary Key Violation issue [ famous issue due to flaw in Hibernate PooledOptimizer implementation ] in our Production environment which has 8 cluster member and using Hibernate 3.2.5, After that, we have changed the Hibernate version to 3.6.10. However we still have the Primary Key Violation issue for some instances during high load processing. I have rechecked the PooledOptimiser and it looks fine now, there is no multiple nextrVal() call.

For your information, We are using eHcache.

Could someone through some light on it ? where can be the problem ? or Probable cause of the issue.

Comment: Which issue? What's the stack trace? What's the code causing it?

Comment: edited ... The issue is the famous Primary Key Violation issue in Cluster environment due to bug in PooledOptimizer[ Hibernate version 3.2.5 ]